# Suppose $A$ is linked to $B$ and $B$ is linked to $C$. Will $A$ appear to be linked to $C$?

Tags: discussion, linked-questions

So, a very useful tool is to look at the "linked" questions. How does this work? I think it should act as a sort of connected component. So that when you look for the questions linked to $A$ you don't only get the questions that where directly closed as being duplicates of $A$, but also any other questions that may be involved with $A$ in some way. Does it works like that right now?

Comment: I wonder how many links we'd end up with if we make linking transitive. I bet there's some very large connected components on this site.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I had a program a while back that would find connected components of duplicate closures; there were some components with around 20 questions, I think.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, it does not work this way.

According to the [tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/linked-questions/info) (maybe somebody can find a more official source):

> The "Linked Questions" sidebar is a user-generated list of related questions shown when viewing a question. Its content comes from questions that users have linked in the question, their answers, or in comments.

I will add that both questions linked in a particular post and questions linking to this post are added to the list. See also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4662/what-links-here/4663#4663). (You may notice that your question is now in the [list of linked questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4662) for that post.)

---

I do not think that such feature would be useful. Just take, as an example, a question, which asks for a proof of some frequently used fact. This question might be linked in many other answers as a reference for an auxiliary result. All questions, where an answerer used this post as a reference, would be linked to each other.

Answer (score 1):

No. I just tested it. I took a random question with a linked question and posted it in an now deleted comment. Post $B$ did show up, but post $C$ didn't.

However, I think that this could be very useful. I think it would be better if you posted this at meta.stackexchange.com.